# Running mstest.exe with a web test that calls another web test

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, mstest, webtest

I have a web test, let's call it WebTestParent that calls another web test, WebTestChild.
There is no problem when I run it from the IDE, but when I try running it from the command line using mstest, like this:

```
C:\MySolution> mstest.exe /testmetadata:"Tests.vsmdi" /test:"WebTestParent.webtest" /testsettings:"local.testsettings"
```

I get this error:

```
Cannot find the test 'WebTestChild' with storage 'C:\MySolution\somesubfolder\WebTestChild.webtest'.
```

The file local.testsettings has "Enable deployment" checked.

Did anyone experience this and maybe found a solution?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not familiar with web tests but I have done this with unit tests. I belive that your problem is not the call from one to test to the other. Maybe your 'WebTestChild' (or both tests) does not belong on the 'TestList' in your 'Tests.vsmdi' file.

If you have not a list for your tests then you should create one. Check [here](http://blog.bobcravens.com/2010/02/use-mstest-to-run-your-tests-via-command-line/) for more details.

Comment: Thanks, I was actually using test lists, the text was simplified for the sake of the example. 
However, the problem "magically" went away after I ran Clean Solution then built the code again ...

Comment: Yeah, sometimes all it needs is just a Rebuilt :)